# Action Script External SWF Fill Screen

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

My AS3 code:

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest("midos.swf"));
addChild(ldr);
```

But my swf resolution is 720x460.

And my project resolution 720x480. How i can fill my swf all to project screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//assuming that you want to scale it based on your stage. If not, just provide correct value
var targetHeight:Number = stage.stageHeight;    
var scale:Number = targetHeight / ldr.height;    
ldr.scaleY = scale;    
//if you want to scale proportionally    
ldr.scaleX = scale;
```